# As const is ignored when there is a type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'd like to constrain an object to be of a certain type, but also to cast it "as const", so that certain properties could be typed literally. However, when I use "as const" with a type definition as in the code below, the inferred type isn't literal - "as const" is ignored.

```
interface IFilterBase {
   type: string
   ...
}

const COST_FILTER: IFilterBase = {
   type: "cost",
   ...
} as const
```

In the code above, "as const" is ignored. `COST_FILTER.type` is inferred as a `string`, not as `"cost"`.

Is there a way to constrain `COST_FILTER` to be implement `IFilterBase` type, yet for it's properties to be inferred "as const"?

Comment: Are you sure you can export as `const`, which has special meaning in Typescript?

Comment: No easy way at the moment but here is an issue tracking a feature request that will help, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31062

Comment: @zmbq, My experience is that I can export. Anyway I'll delete the export statement as it's irrelevant to the question :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you specify the type explicitly typescript will only check for compatibility with the interface. There is a proposal as outlined in comments to support this in the language.

Until that happens, we can play around with the inference rules for a functions and tuples and literals:

- A literal type will be inferred (or better said preserved) if it is assigned in a position that is typed as a generic type parameter constrained to a type that can have literals
- A tuple will be inferred if an array is assigned to a position that is typed as a generic type parameter constrained to `[unknown] | unknown[]`.

With these rules, we can just create a recursive mapped type to map the properties of the original type to a new type that contains such generic type parameters. We don't separate type parameters for every property, one parameter will do for literals and one for tuples. This is just enough to hint to the compiler what we want.

```
type WithLiterals<T, L, LTuple> =  
    T extends string| number | boolean | null | undefined ? T & L :
    {
        [P in keyof T]: 
            WithLiterals<T[P], L, LTuple> & (T[P] extends Array<any> ? LTuple: unknown)
    }

type DeepReadonly<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>
}

function asConst<TInterface>()
{
    return function<
        LTuple extends [unknown] | unknown[],
        L extends string | boolean | number, T extends WithLiterals<TInterface, L, LTuple>>(o: T): DeepReadonly<T> {
        return o as any
    }
}

type IFilterBase = {
    type: "cost" | "other",
    displayName: string | undefined,
    nr: number,
    nrUnion: 1 | 2,
    subObj : {
        a: string;
    }
    arr: string[]
    larr: ("A" | "B")[]
    mixedarr: (number | string)[],
    oArray: Array<{
        a: string
    }>
}

export const COST_FILTER = asConst<IFilterBase>()({
   type: "other",
   nr: 1,
   nrUnion: 1,
   displayName: "Cost",
   subObj: {
       a: "A"
   },
   arr: ["A", "B"],
   larr: ["A"],
   mixedarr: [1, ""],
   oArray: [
       { a: ""}
   ]
})
```

Typed as :

```
export const COST_FILTER : DeepReadonly<{
    type: "other";
    nr: 1;
    nrUnion: 1;
    displayName: "Cost";
    subObj: {
        a: "A";
    };
    arr: ["A", "B"];
    larr: ["A"];
    mixedarr: [1, ""];
    oArray: [{
        a: "";
    }];
}>
```

[Link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIHUCWoAWAZZ0BOBDANgM4A8AKgDSxoVokCuke0AfLALyyzAccmzQAeoaADsAJgVgFQWRMIDmAH1jDaAWwBG2WEvUB7XYxzDty2njwnaY6ADNZ0UbAD8sXgDJKsAFxduAb19ubgBtAAVYWVgAa2hwXRtXAF0vTiC07iRUDCFcQlIwxOpqOgZmWA8AChICvkERcVgAQSxccCIjcBYXGnpGFKso4V0Ad2EASkDYAF8QCBhYABFoaEgAJWgcUV1hPDaSFnYAoKwNrZ3wWDCI4xi4hJJkxeW10+3d-NDEpmAZ4BsrADGoEQ21gOAIAGFtlJSABJYQ5Gw4AHMCoTI7cE6gWhYYz-YRAkHCIiTII9Uq1IRiCTBAZDUaJSzCQYjYTBQqk7hoSn1CRSGTyEx6AwbYxKFQabAUXgCKkNTLoTC5YiwgBiiDwOQAQuDoEVKCVGEwmBVdCkSGMUksVutNm89iwMeksTjjLowRIOpMZr85nA1Rrtbq2LAnbA-SkAEQA3RSSMmSO6VDYSNkSaiRAEBg4cAAORwqmgKX5sjkTNEtnsojTQWEWBSEs0WBr3DrAFVhESUgBGEwAJhbHAItHUAHl1AArbyhzkcHDF6SlgDc3smOBaC4FcnZkzw6-rsAqkca8aUka1kbGO6CqkQ-Ac+5SFUbWiUJfkV45QV0zVaKV-OZEGGQTzpIi7yN63y-AIkC6FgoCwDGwhSLAEKjgAyiQAD6qqwjQACiqwhuCULIaARABpq2A6gQqJjBUToRrAibJlgqaBHWPaDu2nbbFxgQZlme55gWRbMVCcaDsOY6TikwFzlGJ6BFMg6Ppcx6psxF5fhwe4bupJ46bAt73qIanBN2FCRpGRk-i0OYpMEs5+GCUaRjM3CJD8EwgEAA)

Comment: Thanks! The function returned from asConst expects 3 type params, but for `COST_FILTER` it only receives one type param. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BenCarp it's a curried function. Since we don't have partial type argument inference we need to specify the target interface in the first call `asConst<IFilterBase>()` and then call the returned function

Comment: Is there a way for as const to call the inner function imediately, so it's usage is more friendly? Something like: `const COST_FILTER = asConst<IFilterBase>({objLiteral})`

Comment: @BenCarp unfortunately no. I use a bunch of generic type parameters on the inner function, putting all of them on `asConst` means we either let all of them be inferred or all of the are specified, what we want is to specify `IFilterBase` while letting the compiler infer the rest which is not possible without the fabled partial argument inference (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349)

Answer (score 3):

This could be achieved using a dummy validating function.

```
const validateType = <T> (obj:T) => undefined
```

All that is left is to call it with the type and object:

```
const COST_FILTER: IFilterBase = {
   type: "cost",
   displayName: "Cost",
   fields: costFilterFields,
} as const

validateType<FilterBase>(COST_FILTER) // Will show an error if types don't match.
```

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, What do you think? Seems to work just as well.

Comment: Yeah, that works, if you don't mind the check being separate from the initialization.